# Omnivore vs Carnivore territory size

Tags: mammals, diet, territoriality

Edit: Large carnivores require lots of territory. What about bears? They're omnivores. How much does that count?

Is there anywhere I could find weight/territory ratios for mammals, depending on diet? Does necessary territory matter so much depending on the diet of a large mammal?

Thanks

Comment: Bears (depending on species) are omnivorous

Comment: Yep. Realized I was wrong. But the territory size is still something I'd like to find an answer for, if possible

Comment: Also consider that elephants, giraffes, rhinos etc. Are large herbivores and have large territory/ranges

Comment: Any answer is going to vary quite a bit, depending on the productivity of the land in question.  It would take much less area to support a bear in say the lush forest/stream environment of southwest Alaska, than in the near-desert eastern Sierra.